# Xpath Get Two Values Out Of Query

Tags: php, xpath

I have this query that gets two values from two different elements, one is a div with some content and one is a link

```
$tableRows = $xpath->query('//div[@id="div1"]/div[@id="div2"]/div[1] | 
//div[@id="div1"]/div[@id="div2"]/div[3]//div[a][1]');
foreach ($tableRows as $row) {
echo $row->nodeValue,"<br><br>";
}
```

Right now it is outputing the div contents and the anchor text of the link, i want to be able to store the div content in to a variable and the href value of the link in another variable, how could i do that

EDIT

```
$div = array();
$link = array();
$div = $xpath->query('//div[@id="div1"]/div[@id="div2"]/div[1]'); 
$link = $xpath->query('//div[@id="div1"]/div[@id="div2"]/div[3]//div[a][1]//@href');
$k=0;
$i = count($div);
while($k<=$i){
echo $div->items[$k]->nodeValue.'<br><br>';
echo $link->items[$k++]->nodeValue.'<br><br>';
}
```

Just blank screen

Full Code with real div id's and so on

```
$curl = curl_init('http://mp3skull.com/mp3/psy.html'); //example 'psy' will eventually be a variable looped
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10');
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$div = array();
$link = array();
$div = $xpath->query('//div[@id="song_html"]/div[@id="right_song"]/div[1]');
$link = $xpath->query('//div[@id="song_html"]/div[@id="right_song"]/div[3]//div[a]   [1]//@href');
$k=0;
$i = count($div);
while($k<=$i){
echo $div->items[$k]->nodeValue.'<br><br>';
echo $link->items[$k++]->nodeValue.'<br><br>';
}
```

Comment: What this are silly kind of game? Asking question taking part of the answer, creating a new question and deleting the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?

    $curl = curl_init('http://mp3skull.com/mp3/psy.html'); //example 'psy' will eventually be a variable looped
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10');
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);


    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $div_array = array();
    $link_array = array();
    $div = $xpath->query('//div[@id="song_html"]/div[@id="right_song"]/div[1]');
    $link = $xpath->query('//div[@id="song_html"]/div[@id="right_song"]/div[3]//div[a][1]//@href');



    for ($i = 0; $i < $div->length; $i++) {
         array_push($div_array, $div->item($i)->nodeValue);
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $link->length; $i++) {
         array_push($link_array, $link->item($i)->nodeValue);
    }
    $i = 0;
    $m = count($div_array);


    while ($i<=$m)
    {
    echo $div_array[$i].'<br><br>'; 
    echo $link_array[$i++].'<br><br>';  
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Sorry i don't understand

Comment: Could you place a bit of code, i don't really get what you mean by point to the div, i already have the link from the query i just need to output the href of it

Comment: post what you have! you have the link but u need the href? the herf is the link... im confused aswell :)

Comment: I have posted what i have, when i output the above code i get the content fron the div (first part of query) and also the anchor text of the link (second part) but i want the href value as in <a href="this">not this</a>

Comment: try changing the line in your for loop to what i posted in the last line of my answer

Comment: sry silly me ok just tell me what div out of that list actually has the href in it ....

Comment: does this list 1 text of a link currently   div[@id="div1"]/div[@id="div2"]/div[1]

Comment: i edited answer should get the link

Comment: try that if it works we can move foreward

Comment: Just outputs the div content not the link or anchor text

Comment: mind sharing the link your trying to parse... that should grab the href

Comment: i made 1 more small edit

Comment: Okay i manged to get the href, now when i output $row->nodeValue; i get both the content from the div and the href which is what i want but i need to get them both in separate variables, how can i split them

Comment: ok is row 1 the div and row 2 the link?

Comment: Yeah i changed it too //@href before your edit, but both ways work

Comment: Yeah the first part of the query before the | is for the div and after is for the link

Comment: is there more then 1 div and link ?

Comment: Yes but they are all in the same format as above, there just looped. which is why i loop through each one to echo out the data, i would just like to have something like $divContent = $row->onlyDivContentNotLink and $link = $row->onlyHrefOfLinksNotDivContent

Comment: look at answer...the array will contain them individually so you can reference them separately ...is this what your looking for? That should echo out just as you had it before

Comment: please give me a check mark and thumbs up if its what your looking for! its to the left of my answer at the top.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array

Comment: see my edit forgot the node value

Comment: Check my edit to original post

Comment: grr see my correction its been a while sry I asked for a link so i could try it for you but anyways should work

Comment: No problem you've been a great help, with your new edits its still a blank screen

Comment: I have added the full code with the link to the site so you can test it yourself

Comment: trying now...give me  sec

Comment: I tried your original code and it doint work???

Comment: is this what you want http://redwirelogic.com/teststuff/test.php

Comment: its working see my post above sorry took me a little

Comment: that should be prefect ... they are in seperate arrays and everything :) happy coding

Comment: Sorry i had to go to the shop, i will check it out

Comment: That works, i really appreciate your help, is there something else i can do aside from thumbs up, i feel i owe you more.

Comment: Lol your welcome! Are you a member on linked in? If so look me up and endorse me!https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=195560714 other then that im happy your happy. If ya need me again thetylercox@gmail.com